# In Frontier Elite 2, which songs are part of the soundtrack?

Tags: game-music-identification, frontier-elite-2

So far I've found these which I believe are in the soundtrack (available music to choose from in the game):

- In the hall of the mountain king
- Blue danube waltz
- A night on the bare mountain
- Ride of the valkyries
- Hut of Baba Yaga
- Jupiter, the bringer of jollity

(Not entirely sure about that last one)

Which ones am I missing? The Wikipedia article states that there are two custom pieces of music as well but I'm not sure if those have names or not. I'm not sure if it's different for the different platforms but if it makes any difference I'm looking for the soundtrack for the AMIGA version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not know what (if any) differences exist between different versions of the game, but the answer below is correct for the DOS version.

Firstly if you have a copy of the game you can run, you can see the list of tracks available from the options menu (in the DOS version, this is accessible from the main cockpit screen after pressing `Esc` twice). Screenshot below.

[image: Frontier options menu]

As you can see, the songs listed are:

- In The Hall of the Mountain King - Edvard Grieg
- Frontier Main Theme - David Lowe *(original music)*
- Baba Yaga - Modest Mussorgsky
- Night on Bare Mountain - Modest Mussorgsky
- Frontier Second Theme - David Lowe *(original music)*
- Ride of the Valkyries - Richard Wagner
- The Blue Danube - Johann Strauss II
- The Great Gates of Kiev - Modest Mussorgsky

It's perhaps worth mentioning that the versions in the game are abridged arrangements - the original classical pieces are often longer.

**Update:** This user-submitted [screenshot](http://www.mobygames.com/game/amiga/frontier-elite-ii/screenshots/gameShotId,310363/) at Mobygames shows an options screen with an identical list of tracks, claiming to be from the Amiga version.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Pretty much confirms my list. Unfortunately the Frontier themes aren't on Spotify ;)

Comment: There used to be some way of extracting them if you have the original disk. Not sure if they're actually midi files though, so might not sound like they did in game. This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSaP-Bva9_g takes me back :)